# My code doesn't output the full parametric equation only the first value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am trying to find the parametric equations for a certain set of plots, however when I implement the code I only get the first value back. The code is from a website, as I am not very proficient in python. I am  using 3.6.5. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy as sp
from fractions import Fraction



def trigSeries(x):
      f=sp.fft(x)
      n=len(x)
      A0=abs(f[0])/n
      A0=Fraction(A0).limit_denominator(1000)
      hn=np.ceil(n/2)
      f=f[1:int(hn)]
      A=2*abs(f)/n
      P=sp.pi/2-sp.angle(f)
      A=map(Fraction,A)
      A=map(lambda a:a.limit_denominator(1000),A)
      P=map(Fraction,P)
      P=map(lambda a:a.limit_denominator(1000),P)
      s=map(str,A)
      s=map(lambda a: a+"*np.sin(", s)
      s=map(lambda a,b,c :
            a+str(b)+"-2*sp.pi*t*"+str(c)+")",
                  s,P,range(1,len(list(P))+1))
      s="+".join(s)
      s=str(A0)+"+"+s
      return s


x=[5041,4333,3625,3018,2816,2967,3625,4535,5800,6811,7823,8834,8429,7418,6305,5193,4181,3018,3018,3777,4687,5496,6912,7974,9087]
y=[4494,5577,6930,8825,10990,13426,14509,15456,15456,15186,15321,17486,19246,21005,21276,21952,22223,23712,25877,27501,28178,28448,27636,26960,25742]

xf=trigSeries(x)
print(xf)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact output you're expecting?

Comment: Something like this  ```48/11+
 3701/783*np.sin(1421/321-2*sp.pi*t*1)+
 121/804*np.sin(1-2*sp.pi*t*2)+
 184/833*np.sin(3551/921-2*sp.pi*t*3)+
 369/773*np.sin(356/831-2*sp.pi*t*4)+
 46/755*np.sin(2841/865-2*sp.pi*t*5) ```

Comment: A good debugging technique here would be to go through each statement in the function one at a time and test the outputs to see the exact point where it does something you don't expect.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make the code to work but i could not manage to do it.
The problem id that when you call `map(...)` You create an iterator, so in order to print it's content you have to do:

```
for data in iterator:
     print(data)
```

The problem her is that when you apply the `lambda` function if you cycle over the variable it returns nothing.

You colud convert all the `lambda` in `for` cycles, but you have to think over the triple-argument `lambda`.

Comment: This is true but I would suggest changing all the statements like `A=map(...)` to `A=list(map(...))` and then doing `print(A)` on the next line as a quick way to debug this if the OP is not familiar with the Python debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the step

```
s=map(lambda a,b,c :
    a+str(b)+"-2*sp.pi*t*"+str(c)+")",
          s,P,range(1,len(list(P))+1))
```

it returns empty list. To resolve it, convert `s` and `P` to lists just before feeding to this `map` function. Add two lines above.

```
s = list(s)
P = list(P)
```

Output for your example

> 134723/25+308794/391*np.sin(-1016/709-2*sp.pi*t*1)+2537094/989*np.sin(641/835-2*sp.pi*t*2)+264721/598*np.sin(-68/241-2*sp.pi*t*3)+285344/787*np.sin(-84/997-2*sp.pi*t*4)+118145/543*np.sin(-190/737-2*sp.pi*t*5)+281400/761*np.sin(-469/956-2*sp.pi*t*6)+1451/8*np.sin(-563/489-2*sp.pi*t*7)+122323/624*np.sin(-311/343-2*sp.pi*t*8)+115874/719*np.sin(-137/183-2*sp.pi*t*9)+171452/861*np.sin(-67/52-2*sp.pi*t*10)+18152/105*np.sin(-777/716-2*sp.pi*t*11)+24049/125*np.sin(-107/76-2*sp.pi*t*12)

Comment: I have no idea why empty list is returned from this particular map function. I tried to replicate it and was not able to.